# PHP form doesn´t save the accent marks into MySQL DB

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I store info into a MySQL Database via a PHP Form, the problem is that is a person inputs into the name field José Molína in the database it saves JOSé MOLíNA so it convert the accent mark into a non legible name and when I displys the info of the database in a form it shows Jos Molna (doesn´t show the letters with the accent marks).

the info of my table is ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 and the forms captures the info from a Wordpress site, could you please tell me what is the problem?

this is the way I sent the info to the database

```
$strNombres = htmlspecialchars(rtrim($_POST['nNombres']));
     $Nombres= filter_var($strNombres, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
```

the I tried with this one but no solution

```
$strNombres = strtoupper((rtrim($_POST['nNombres'])));
     $Nombres = htmlentities($strNombres, ENT_QUOTES,'UTF-8');
```

to the manager:
since you closed this question, can you tell me where is the duplicate sign where the question was edited? besides of that I would like to close my account, how come you close a question?

I just send a message via twitter for this.

[image]

Comment: make everything UTF-8 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: Your database is in the wrong encoding! UTF-8 all the things! You'll need to use one of the character encoding converter functions such as http://php.net/manual/en/function.mb-convert-encoding.php if you don't

Comment: [Handling Unicode Front To Back In A Web App](http://kunststube.net/frontback/)

Comment: Thanks everyone, another quickly question, how can I report an administrator, there are some that simply close the question in this case deceze

Answer (score -1):

You need to change the charset of your table

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET charset_name;
```

In your case you should replace `tbl_name` with your table name

```
ALTER TABLE tbl_name CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET 'UTF-8';
```

Comment: that may not be enough

Comment: db engine ?? innodb?